# Transition effect when switching display:none - display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a fade-in/fade-out effect when switching from display:none to display:block and the other way around. This is the code I have:

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(idInfo) {
var sel = document.getElementById('contentDivs').getElementsByClassName('x');
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('content'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
}
window.onload = function() {showDiv('1');}
```

HTML / PHP:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href='' onclick='showDiv("1");return false'><li>Button 1</li></a>
        <a href='' onclick='showDiv("2");return false'><li>Button 2</li></a>
        <a href='' onclick='showDiv("3");return false'><li>Button 3</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentDivs">
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
        echo('
        <div id="content'.$i.'" class="x">
            <div id="box1">
                <p>Text '.$i.'</p>
            </div>
            <div id="box2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content '.$i.'</td>
                        <td>Content '.$i.'</td>
                        <td>Content '.$i.'</td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>');
    }?>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to make this possible? I've tried several things, but I cannot figure out the right way to do this. Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The loop executes in milliseconds so you won't see any transitions.

Comment: It's not about the loop, but about the switching between display:none to display:block. The loop executes on refresh, but after you can click on the buttons to change the content. And I want the content to be faded-in/out when another button is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's no out-of-the box way of doing this. There are a couple of ways of doing this in a slightly different way using the CSS3 `opacity` property:

First, add a CSS declaration in which you add an `active` class and a CSS3 transition:

```
#menu ul a {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

#menu ul a.inactive {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Then, have your JavaScript add the `inactive` class. Also, after one second, change the `a` to `display: none`.

```
function showDiv(idInfo) {
    var newId = 'content' + idInfo;
    var sel = document.getElementById('contentDivs').getElementsByClassName('x');
    for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
        // Fade In all our currently viewable divs
        sel[i].className += 'inactive';
        // If this is NOT our new div, hide after 1 second (transition time)
        if (sel[i].id !== newId)
            setTimeout(function () {
                sel[i].style.display = 'none';
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    var newEl = document.getElementById(newId);
    // Make sure our new element is being displayed
    newEl.style.display = 'block';
    // Add the `inactive` class in order to make the opacity 0
    newEl.className += 'inactive';
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Remove the `inactive` className in order to trigger the fade in
        newEl.className = '';
    }, 0);
}
window.onload = function() {showDiv('1');}
```

You could also do this with JavaScript (NO CSS Required):

```
function showDiv(idInfo) { 
     var newId = 'content'+idInfo;
     var $elements = $('#contentDivs').find('.x');
     $elements.fadeOut(1000, funciton () {
         var $newElement = $('#' + newId);
         $newElement.fadeIn();
     });
}
window.onload = function() {showDiv('1');}
```

Comment: This is a complete answer although you only need one setTimeout since all of them are occurring at the same time. Or better yet, use transitionend event so that you can define the length of the transition in css.

Comment: 1)Transition rule in `#menu ul a.inactive` is unnecessary. 2)Using both CSS transitions rule and jQuery fade function is not a good practice 3) `display:none` is different from `opacity:0`

Comment: I just added an edit. What I meant was for these to be two separate solutions. The jQuery solution doesn't need the CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. The first option (non-JQuery) does not work. As I apply it, everything shows and clicking links doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 2):

If the display of an element and the transition of an element begin on the same frame, the transition will never occur.

You have to set the display of the element, and then do

```
setTimeout(function() {
     // start transition
}, 0);
```

Calling setTimeout of 0 will cause the transition to take place on the next frame.